# sort contacts in android application in Alphabetical order according to display name

Tags: android, sorting, android-contacts

i know this question has been asked already but i cant seem to find anything that works for me from the content here and on other web resources. i want to  display contacts in alphabetical order according to   the DISPLAY  NAME but they are sorted according to the number of the contact here is my code.

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listview;
    private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_list);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Cursor phone = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phone.moveToNext()) {

            String name = phone
                    .getString(phone
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phone
                    .getString(phone
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
            objContact.setName(name);
            objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);
            list.add(objContact);
        }
        phone.close();
```

can any one help me to sort my contacts by rewriting this code
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured out what to do, I changed the code to this and it worked fine.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Comment: Thanks for working that out.  nHelped me out with a similar problem.